# Как переслать сообщения из группы в мой чат бот в телеграмме?

Tags: python, telebot, бот, чат

Всем привет, у меня не работает код при пересылки смс с группы в мой тг бот, группа моя, я добавила чат бота администратором, что я пишу не так? помогите пожалуйста

```
 import logging
import telebot
from telebot import types
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5616570094:AAHOJMlM5XaeRLr9N1Nkm9HLGF9bAJzAjVQ')
chatID = '-1001508292766'# тг канал откуда нужно пересыать смс
bot_chat_id = '5616570094'# мой бот 
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def website(message):
    mess = f'Привет , <b>{message.from_user.first_name} </b> \n\n Я помогу тебе получать много заявок по твоей профессии.\n\n Выбери свою профессию: '
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode ='html')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)#row_width=1 - сколько кнопок в ряд
    design = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Дизайнер", callback_data='desig')
    target = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Таргетолог", callback_data = 'targe')
    markup.add(design, target)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберете', reply_markup = markup)
#ответ по кнопке
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    if call.message:
        if call.data == "desig":
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы выбрали Дизайн." )
        elif call.data == 'targe':
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы выбрали Таргет.")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def checkbot_text(message):
    bot.forward_message(bot_chat_id, chatID, message.message_id)
```